# How does starter work without a trigger wire terminal?

Tags: diesel, starter, fiat, punto, solenoid

Changing the starter on my 2007 Fiat 1.3 diesel. There is no "trigger wire" terminal. Instead the light wire is in a plastic housing which is bolted on under the battery feed.

How does this work?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which exact vehicle model are you talking about here? (I don't know if it will matter, but it might help us figure out your issue.)

Comment: its fiat grande punto 1.3 multijet diesel. the starter appears common across fiat 1.3 diesel of this vintage across the board

Comment: If the images I see are the correct starter, there are two terminals on the back of the solenoid: one where the main power goes in; separate post which provides a connection down to the motor. These types have a separate relay which turns on the juice from the battery. Older Ford starters worked the same way. It looked [something like this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71VNghIBjSL._SL1500_.jpg). Not sure how your Punto is wired, though.